# The Event in the DIV Not working after reload

Tags: jquery

I have the code below to sort the table column "Created Date" when user clicks.
Please note that "`IntNote_CreatedDate`" is the ID of the table TH tag.

```
    var f_CreatedDate = 1;
    $("#IntNote_CreatedDate").on("click", function()
    {
        //alert("Hey");
        f_CreatedDate *= -1;
        var n = $(this).prevAll().length;
        sortTable("#tblIntNotes", f_CreatedDate, n); // call the sortTable function.... working fine
    });
```

This is working fine. Now I have a popUp window to add note with this code below and it adds the note then refresh the Parent DIV container for the note.  This also works fine.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    updateParentDIV = function() {
        var url = opener.location.href + " #refreshNotes"
        //alert("url: " + url)

        // This method works for both IE and FireFox
        window.opener.$("div#divNotes").load(
            url, function(){
            window.close();
        });
    };
});
```

The problem is after the Parent DIV refreshed, the event "`$("#IntNote_CreatedDate").on("click", function()`" no longer recognize or work anymore. Somehow, it is not execute anymore, no error.

Please advise how can I refresh the parent window DIV and still preserve the event "`$("#IntNote_CreatedDate").on("click", function()`" works.

Comment: Have you checked if the event delegation exists in the DOM of the pop up ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use the delegate version of .on() and attach it to a parent of your div.  Something along the lines of this should be close: (not tested)

```
$(document).on("click", "#IntNote_CreatedDate", function(){.....});
```

basically your current version attaches to the dom object that exists at the time the page is loaded.  When your div is rewritten it loses the event.  By attaching to the parent with a selector for your element, you are saying to run this event for any child of mine that matches the selector, now or in the future.

Read the "Direct and delegated events" section of the documentation:
http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: quick question.  To be safe, should I always use the "delegate version of .on() " for all my events in the future?  It looks like this method works for now and future which is better.  any drawback of always using "delegate version of .on()"? like performance slower than Direct Events?

Comment: @Milacay I have not tested it at all, but I would speculate that there is a bit of extra overhead involved in the delegate version.  Probably not enough to notice in most cases.  I think the documentation also mentioned a few special cases where the delegates wont work.  Overall, I would probably use the delegates unless I noticed a problem.